# Facebook API carousel ads previews

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to create a preview of a carousel facebook ad before the ad is created itself. This is possible for other types of ads, but I am unsure if it can be done for carousel ads,

The below line from documentation would suggest not, unless there is a way to do this without the "object_story_id". Perhaps someone knows of a different method?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/generatepreview/v2.5

"Create an multi-product ad preview using object_story_id. To get an object_story_id, you must first create a Multi-Product Ad"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can preview a carousel ad without `object_story_id`. You can create a carousel ad page post in the same call with the ad creative API as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/carousel-ads#create). Once you have this, you can make a call to `creative_id?fields=object_story_id` to retrieve the post ID. Then you can preview what the post will look like by going to `facebook.com/post-id`.

If I am not mistaken, I think this will only create an unpublished post which serves as an ad creative and does not actually create an ad. If you want to create an ad out of it then you can use the `creative_id` in `act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads` endpoint as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/v2.6#Creating).